# Quasiconcave function that is partially infinite

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Why is the following function quasiconcave? The domain are real vectors.

$$f(x)=\min \{ k | \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| > 1 \}$$
$$f(x)=\infty \text{ if } \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

w.l.o.g., assume $f(y) \le f(x)$.

---

1. If $f(y)$ is finite:

Note the following:

$\sum_1^{f(y)-1} |y_i| \le 1$
and
$\sum_1^{f(y) - 1} |x_i| \le 1$

This implies that
$$\sum_1^{f(y)-1} |\lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) y_i| \le \sum_1^{f(y)-1} \lambda |x_i| + (1-\lambda) |y_i| \le \lambda + 1 - \lambda \le 1$$

2. if $f(y) = \infty$,

   $$\sum_1^{n} |\lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) y_i| \le \sum_1^{n} \lambda |x_i| + (1-\lambda) |y_i| \le \lambda + 1 - \lambda \le 1$$

---

From this, we may conclude that $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \ge f(y) = \min\{f(x), f(y)\}$. QED.